# making types: Add data type and evaluator that is of an unmatched type

Tags: haskell

I have added | Lit Int and | Add Exp Exp to the data type as seen below, along with the evaluation. However I get an error "Couldn't match expected type ‘Var’ with actual type ‘Int’".

```
data Exp = V Var
    | B Bool
    | L Exp
    | A Exp Exp
    | Lit Int
    | Add Exp Exp
data Var = VZ |VS Var

eval:: Exp -> Var
eval (Lit n)     = n
eval (Add e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
```

How can I add Int and Add to the data type, along with the evaluation, but maintain the following code as is. Is this possible?

```
data Exp = V Var
    | B Bool
    | L Exp
    | A Exp Exp
data Var = VZ |VS Var
```

---

I have added an instance to resolve this, as seen below, but now I have the error "Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declaration: Add e1 e2 = (Lit e1) + (Lit e2)":

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Exp = V Var
    | B Bool
    | L Exp
    | A Exp Exp
    | Lit Int
    | Add Exp Exp
data Var = VZ |VS Var

eval:: Exp -> Var
eval (Lit n)     = n
eval (Add e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2

instance Num Var where
    Lit e = e

instance Num Var where
    Add e1 e2 = (Lit e1) + (Lit e2)
```

Comment: `eval` has type `Exp -> Var`, so that means that `eval e1` is a `Var`. But you can not add two `Var`s together, or at least not without defining *how* to do that.

Comment: How can I define how to do that?

Comment: you define it as an `instance` of `Num`, so `instance Num Var where ...`.

Comment: What do VZ and VS stand for?

Comment: VZ and VS are part of code that I am working with, I don't actually see them defined further so I can probably drop it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have made the requested edits but still have an issue. I have updated the above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have gotten mixed up along the way. I believe `Var` represents a *free variable* in [De Bruijn notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index). You're missing an encoding of *values*. This could look something vaguely like

```
data Value
  = IntVal !Int
  | BoolVal !Bool
  | Closure { environment :: [Value]
            , expr :: Exp }
```

Now you'll want `eval :: Exp -> Value` to evaluate expressions. There's lots of work left.