# Polymorphic evaluator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I edit the following code so that I don't have so many evaluators (which right now reflect various result types)? I want a single evaluator so that I don't know in advance the type of the result. I want one evaluator for the whole language. Do I need to add a value type for Exp to do this? How would this look like? What kind of value type and how would I edit the current eval functions in order to reflect this new polymorphic type?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Exp = V Var
    | B Bool
    | MyInt Int
    | And Exp Exp
    | Or Exp Exp
    | Not Exp
    | Mult Exp Exp
    | UnaryNeg Exp
    | LEQ Exp Exp
    | LESST Exp Exp
    | Add Exp Exp 
    | POLYEQ Exp Exp
data Var = VZ |VS Var

eval:: Exp -> Int
eval (MyInt e1)     = e1
eval (UnaryNeg e1)     = - (eval e1)
eval (Mult e1 e2) = eval e1 * eval e2
eval (Add e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2

eval0:: Exp -> Bool
eval0 (B e1) = e1
eval0 (Not e1) = not (eval0 e1)
eval0 (And e1 e2) = (eval0 e1) && (eval0 e2)
eval0 (Or e1 e2) = (eval0 e1) || (eval0 e2)
eval0 (LEQ e1 e2) = eval e1 <= eval e2
eval0 (LESST e1 e2) = eval e1 < eval e2

eval1:: Exp -> Bool
eval1 (POLYEQ e1 e2) = eval0 e1 == eval0 e2
```

Comment: Why is `eval1` separated from `eval0`?

Comment: it doesnt need to be here, but my original issue still stands since eval and eval0 return diff types

Comment: The answers to two of your previous questions already explain how to do this, namely [adding a polymorphic type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64528413/246886) and [Add data type and evaluator…](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64526924/246886). Have you tried those solutions? What about them are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution is to have the expression type annotated with what type of result it represents. This will then be a *Generalised Algebraic Data Type*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Exp a where
   V :: Var -> Exp a
   B :: Bool -> Exp Bool
   MyInt :: Int -> Exp Int
   And :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
   POLYEQ :: Exp a -> Exp a -> Exp Bool
   ...
```

Then you need only one evaluation function, whose result will be whatever the type represented by the expression:

```
eval :: Exp a -> a
eval (MyInt e1) = e1
eval (B  e1) = e1
...
```

Comment: Another solution could be to return an `Either Int Bool`. It's probably easier to start with if OP is a beginner. But I agree a GADT would be the best solution otherwise

Comment: Using `Either` only addresses part of the problem, namely returning the value of a well-formed expression like `eval (Add (MyInt 3) (MyInt 5)) == Right 8 :: Either Bool Int`. It doesn't do anything for "malformed" expressions like `Add (MyInt 3) (B False)`. You would need something like `eval :: Exp -> Maybe (Either Bool Int)`, and there's so much boilerplate in the definition that the GADT isn't really that much more complicated in comparison.